# MySQL Query Building - Referral Count (same row join?)

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
Username     Referredby
foobar       
foobar2      foobar
lolcat       foobar
catcat       lolcat
```

What I want: a list of the top referrers, and how many people they have referred.

Do I need to do a self join or something?

Comment: Yes. You need a join or something.

Comment: This can be done by `group by` without any join, just learn SQL, google sql tutorials for that sake, don't ask if you didn't try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think you'd be okay with:

```
 select Referredby, count(*) from thistable 
    group by Referredby order by cnt desc;
```